# Best way to display an image from server in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to display an image in android. Image needs to be taken from the server. What should be the best approach for making sure that the image stored at the server fits with all android device screens. In the image displaying XML I need to display a textview (below the image) also for giving a brief description about the image. Do I have to create the image with a specific height and width or is there any other approach?

Answer (score 1):

You should store a large enough image on the server.

```
// Know the required width of the image
URL url = new URL(remotePath);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
inputStream = (InputStream) urlConnection.getContent();
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, options);
int height = options.outHeight;
int width = options.outWidth;
int sampleSize = requiredWidth / width; // Calculate how you want to sample the images so you can keep the memory small
options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, options);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display on that screen only the image and description below it, you could place  the 2 component in a `LinearLayout` with the orientation vertical and use the `layout_weight` property of the `LinearLayout`, for example you could do something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You could download the image from the server manually or you could use a library like [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), or [webImageLoader](https://github.com/wrapp/WebImage-Android).